# Placing d3.js svg elements inline in HTML

Tags: html, d3.js, svg

I have a (finally) well-behaved responsive d3.js v4 svg chart that I'd like to place inline in my HTML code, i.e. my HTML header and other elements shall be at the top of my window followed by the chart. Instead, the HTML elements are drawn over the chart. I could pad the margins to make it work, but would prefer there were a way to control the vertical ordering of the svg.
Here's some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Plot Viewer</title>
    <script src="js/lib/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>

      h1 {
        margin: 0 0 22px 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #333;
      }

      .line { 
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 3px;
      }

      #chart { 
        float: inherit;
        clear: both;
      }

      .grid line {
        stroke: lightgrey; stroke-opacity: 0.7; shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }

      .grid path { stroke-width: 0;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Solar Insolation, in W/m2</h1>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>

      var chartDiv = document.getElementById("chart");
      var svg = d3.select(chartDiv).append("svg");

      // parse the date time
      var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%m/%d %H:%M");

      function render() {

        $("svg").empty();

        // Extract the width and height that was computed by CSS.
        var width = chartDiv.clientWidth;
        var height = chartDiv.clientHeight;

        // Use the extracted size to set the size of an SVG element.
        svg
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);

        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 55, left: 55},
          width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // set the ranges
        var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

        // define the line
        var valueline = d3.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.solar); });

        // gridlines in x axis function
        function make_x_gridlines() { return d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(24)
        }

        // gridlines in y axis function
        function make_y_gridlines() { return d3.axisLeft(y)
        .ticks(10)
        }

        // Get the data
        d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

          if (error) throw error;

          // format the data
          data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.time = parseTime(d.time);
            d.solar = +d.solar;
          });

          // Scale the range of the data
          x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
          y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.solar; }));

          // Add the valueline path.
          svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline)
            .attr("transform", "translate(40, 10)");

          // make room for text at top of Y axis

          var extraHeight = height + 10;

          // Add the X Axis
          svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(40," + extraHeight + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m/%d %H:%M  ")))
            .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");

          // Add the Y Axis
          svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(40 ,10)")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

          // add the X gridlines
          svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "grid")
              .attr("transform", "translate(40," + extraHeight + ")")
              .call(make_x_gridlines()
                  .tickSize(-height)
                  .tickFormat("")
              )

          // add the Y gridlines
          svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "grid")
              .attr("transform", "translate(40 ,10)")
              .call(make_y_gridlines()
                  .tickSize(-width)
                  .tickFormat("")
              )

        });
      }

      render();

      // Redraw based on the new size whenever the browser window is resized
      window.addEventListener("resize", render);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and some contents of chart.csv:

```
time,solar
11/30 15:45,56.0
11/30 15:50,121.6
11/30 15:55,60.1
11/30 16:00,62.3
11/30 16:05,65.9
11/30 16:10,85.0
11/30 16:15,109.5
11/30 16:20,116.5
11/30 16:25,141.0
11/30 16:30,367.0
11/30 16:35,387.9
11/30 16:40,490.1
11/30 16:45,419.4
11/30 16:50,513.2
11/30 16:55,409.5
11/30 17:00,455.7
11/30 17:05,373.6
11/30 17:10,586.1
11/30 17:15,550.2
11/30 17:20,479.9
11/30 17:25,552.4
11/30 17:30,638.1
11/30 17:35,662.3
11/30 17:40,683.2
11/30 17:45,704.0
11/30 17:50,691.6
11/30 17:55,711.7
11/30 18:00,538.8
11/30 18:05,453.5
```

Is there a clean way to affix the generated svg element *after* the current header, and before the footer?

I realized there was no float: center attribute, so tried inherit. The funny thing is that it starts vertically small, but every expansion in the y-axis grows the chart without allowing shrinkage when the vertical window size is reduced.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are positioning your chart in the wrong way. Also your HTML is all wrong: `h3` is out of the `<body>`! You should have it this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Plot Viewer</title>

    <style>
      #chart, h1, h3 {
        float: left;
        clear: both;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Solar Insolation, in W/m2</h1>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <h3> Blah, blah, blah...</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note** Your question is about positioning of elements, not really about charts.

#### Example

The following snippet shows you the final result. Once the chart is in there it will render in the flow.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Plot Viewer</title>

    <style>
      h1 {
        margin: 0 0 22px 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #333;
      }
      #chart,h1,h3 {
        float: left;
        clear: both;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Solar Insolation, in W/m2</h1>
    <div id="chart">
      My chart here 
      <div style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:#ff9900"></div>
      </div>
    <h3> Blah, blah, blah...</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is essentially what I already have; I threw in the <h3> just to suggest a footer following the chart. It was in the wrong place, but this still overlays the HTML text on top of the svg. I suspect it is some aspect of my container that is the problem; I am sizing against the window dimensions (clientWidth, clientHeight). The title clearly states it's about positioning of elements. The svg and html seem oblivious of each other, to anthromorphise ;-)

Comment: Your problem is the way your are positioning the `#chart` element. You are specifying an absolute positioning as you specify all 4 directions. Get rid of that and your chart will follow the text flow... Just try as I told you in my answer.

Comment: OK, sorry I missed the float, and that does stack the elements, but my chart ten became fixed at a (narrow) chart width, having lost x-axis responsiveness. Changing the float attr to center now is responsive horizontally, but the y-axis expansion seems to be sticky - it only grows but doesn't shrink back on resize. It's late Friday, i'll attach it with a clearer head tomorrow! Thanks.

Comment: @rattus: Yes, we need mo info here.

Comment: Meant to say, updated the code in the original question.